Second network connection makes internet unreachable
Periodically, my Windows desktop PC is connected to two networks simultaneously.
The first network is a Wi-Fi network that is also connected to the internet via a Wi-Fi router/DSL modem. The router address is 192.168.1.1. My machine can have an address like 192.168.1.115 (assigned by DHCP automatically).
The second network is a physical Ethernet wire connection to another (not the one above) router. This router does not have access to the internet. The router address is 192.168.2.1. My machine can have an address like 192.168.2.248 (assigned by DHCP automatically).
The problem.
I happily use the first Wi-Fi network most of the time, and everything is fine. However, when I connect the Ethernet cable to my PC to access the second network, Windows automatically creates a new route that looks like this:
0.0.0.0  0.0.0.0  192.168.2.1  192.168.2.248  25

Obviously, Windows is trying to be helpful and assumes that since the new network is attached, I want to send all packets through it as well. However, this new route makes packets go through it and as result the PC loses connection to the internet.
This problem is quite easy to solve by removing the newly created route by executing:
route delete -p 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1 metric 25

This solves the problem, and the PC is able to use the first network for the internet and the second for IPs in 192.168.2.* only.
However, once I disconnect and reconnect the Ethernet cable or disable/enable the Ethernet adapter, the route appears again. Unfortunately, it seems that the -p flag in the command above does not make the deletion persistent.
I can programmatically detect this new route and have a process/service running in the background to kill this route as soon as it is created. But it feels like there should be a better and more elegant solution for this.

What if you set the gateway address of the 2nd network to the gateway of the first network? I suspect that will solve the issue entirely. You can also try to just override the DNS server to the ip address of the first network's router. That way, you don't have to completely disable DHCP for the 2nd network.

@LPChip Unfortunately, the 2nd router is not physically connected to the 1st router, so there is no way to specify the 1st as a gateway for the 2nd one. Regarding DNS, when the 2nd network connects, the internet disappears not because of DNS. I cannot even ping 8.8.8.8 at that moment, so it seems like all packets just starting to go through the 192.168.2.1 router which is not connected to the internet.

It sounds like the router on the .2.x subnet is using DHCP to tell your Windows PC to use .2.1 as its default route, and Windows is just doing what it was told.
To fix this, you may need to find a way to tell that DHCP server not to configure a default route on that PC, or you'll need to configure that interface on your PC manually (not DHCP), leaving the default router/gateway field blank.
You could also try telling Windows to consider the Wi-Fi interface to be the higher priority interface, and that may cause the Wi-Fi default route to take precedence over the Ethernet default route.

Brilliant! I hadn't realized that simply switching off DHCP on the second router would stop it from propagating itself to Windows as a default gateway. Thank you so much for this simple and perfect solution!
